# How to navigate from NavigationSplitView to new view opened full screen

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview, navigationsplitview

I want to ask for help with `NavigationSplitView` for iPad app. My idea is to have `NavigationSplitView` where I can display some filters/sections on the left side and list of objects on the right side (in the details section). But when user will tap on object, new view should appear with details. Problem is that `NavigationSplitView` gives me a navigation only in details section while I want to display view full screen. What I came up with is to have `NavigationStack` that has `NavigationSplitView` within it. But once item is tapped it will navigate inside NavigationSplitViews detail section. What will be proper approach for such problem? My current and very simple code for experiment with is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    public var items: [DatabaseObject]?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationSplitView {
                List {
                    Text("Filter 1")
                    Text("Filter 2")
                    Text("Filter 3")
                }
                .navigationTitle("Filters")
            } detail: {
                List {
                    if let items = items {
                        ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                            NavigationLink {
                                Text("Hello. Details for person \(item.name)")
                            } label: {
                                Text(item.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Items")
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is problematic about wrapping `NavigationSplitView` with `NavigationStack`? That seems reasonable to me. That said, also consider using a `fullscreenCover` to show the details.

Comment: It sounds like you don’t need a NavigationSplitView at all. Just use the NavigationStack with an HStack to start.

Comment: @loremipsum I think I will end up with something like this. But I wanted to give a shot.

Comment: @Sweeper problematic part here is that it is opening in details part, like NavigationSplitView is capturing whole navigation.